# R - ggplot width errorbar gone mad

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a problem with the `width` of my **errorbar** in `ggplot2`.

`width=1` seems to work fine

```
dta %>% 
  ggplot(aes(variable, mean, fill = class)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70), colour = 'gray58', linetype = 3) + 
  geom_bar(stat= 'identity', position = 'dodge') + facet_wrap(~sex, ncol = 1) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#FBB4B9', '#AE017E')) +
  theme_minimal(base_family = 'Helvetica') + xlab('') + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=ciL, ymax=ciH), width=1, position='dodge', colour = 'gray22') + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(mean, 'min', sep = '')), size = 5, vjust = -1, position=position_dodge(width=0.9))
```

However, I would like for aesthetical purpose

`width=0.2`

But the bars have gone mad here

```
dta %>% 
  ggplot(aes(variable, mean, fill = class)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70), colour = 'gray58', linetype = 3) + 
  geom_bar(stat= 'identity', position = 'dodge') + facet_wrap(~sex, ncol = 1) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#FBB4B9', '#AE017E')) +
  theme_minimal(base_family = 'Helvetica') + xlab('') + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=ciL, ymax=ciH), width=0.2, position='dodge', colour = 'gray22') + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(mean, 'min', sep = '')), size = 5, vjust = -1, position=position_dodge(width=0.9))
```

Why ?

[image]

```
dta = structure(list(sex = c("women", "women", "men", "men", "women", 
"women"), class = structure(c(1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("Higher Managerial", 
"Lower Managerial", "Intermediate", "Manual and Routine"), class = "factor"), 
variable = c("Child Care", "Child Care", "Child Care", "Child Care", 
"Domestic", "Domestic"), mean = c(50, 37, 38, 31, 52, 55), 
ciH = c(54.2777626665669, 41.5267510169482, 41.8813404146388, 
35.1377348981821, 57.1787075181977, 59.7559083667546), ciL = c(44.9362111325597, 
33.4504179328235, 34.7998822927848, 27.1453701246489, 47.5374496870425, 
49.3765117245696)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("sex", 
"class", "variable", "mean", "ciH", "ciL"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this fix (by using width parameter in ?position_dodge):

```
dta %>% 
  ggplot(aes(variable, mean, fill = class)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70), colour = 'gray58', linetype = 3) + 
  geom_bar(stat= 'identity', position = 'dodge') + facet_wrap(~sex, ncol = 1) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#FBB4B9', '#AE017E')) +
  theme_minimal(base_family = 'Helvetica') + xlab('') + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=ciL, ymax=ciH), width=0.2, position=position_dodge(width=.9), colour = 'gray22') + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(mean, 'min', sep = '')), size = 5, vjust = -1, position=position_dodge(width=0.9))
```

with output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so very much. very grateful !